# Wireshark filter for filtering both destination-source IP address and the protocol

Tags: http, networking, wireshark, sniffer

I want to filter Wireshark's monitoring results according to a filter combination of source, destination ip addresses and also the protocol.
So, right now I'm able to filter out the activity for a destination and source ip address using this filter expression:
(ip.dst == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && ip.src == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) || (ip.dst == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && ip.src == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

This gives me request response activity of the 2 ip addresses which are destination and source both depending upon whether it is a request or a response.
But now, I am getting results for HTTP and TCP both. I want to see results only for HTTP.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(ip.dst == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && ip.src == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) || (ip.dst == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && ip.src == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) && http

Comment: Eeks! I had actually tried that but don't know why it didn't work. Thanks a lot for the solution!!

Comment: Another interesting link on this stuff: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wireshark-filter/

Answer (score 3):

I like (ip.addr==XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX && http) for a single host.  You could also do (ip.addr==XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX or XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX && http) for two hosts.

Comment: It worked for me using the solution provided by Keshi! But, thanks for this though! :)